# How to verify signature from $ cleos get block BLOCKNUM

Tags: cleos, nodeos

How to verify the signature of data returned from `$ cleos get block BLOCKNUM` to insure that the data returned came from the blockchain and not 'spoofed' by a man-in-the-middle?

```
cleos get block 132

{"producer_signature":
  "SIG_K1_JzJjQSJdXdqE9H9JDgXumppkjv2AhpJWNxXuoJzqrQsmNDBqyhrz1TnkRUMT7WbGJwpA3kyj3c9TSthJwfzb22se4CPdbD",
  ...
  "trx": {
    "id": "a4c3cd072387dbb00dd27b99b2ed6d4ea8520239a11a775fdc6036bdc690aa55",
    "signatures": [
      "SIG_K1_KVXChzbL8gnEELY72qXhBd1xYfPkez2AAFtAB1RyiwbtEkt5zRSBSzXwDotdzymB75WLi9e7i4178HXDVk8yAci5tYWTnU"
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can recover public key of the producer which signed the Block.

Take a look at https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc, it contains all the neccessary cryptographic functions you need.